# Ambiguous column name error : SQL count, join, group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I have two tables as below, one table has number of available units (stock), I'm trying to return the stock count of each product category, and joining it with secondary table to view the description and price etc.

When I run the below query, I get "Ambiguous column name 'productID'."

What am I doing wrong?

SQL Query:

```
select productID, count (stock)as available_count
from product_units
join  product_type ON product_type.description = product_units.productID
group by productID
```

This returns an error:

> Ambiguous column name 'productID'.

Table product_type

```
productID  description  price 
101        tent         20.00
102        xltent       50.00
```

Table product_units

```
unitID  productID stock
1       101       1
2       101       1
3       101       1
4       102       1
```

---

Orginal SQL query to get stock count, which works:

```
select productID, count (stock)as available_count
from  product_units
group by productID
```

**I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 with Coldfusion**

Comment: [What does "ambiguous column name" mean?](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-does-ambiguous-column-name-mean.html)

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you rewritten your query as Gordon Linoff suggests, Caludi Sasi?

Comment: Do you get any results, Caludi? Having reproduced your tables, I get : | 101, tent, 20 | 102, xltent, 50 |

Comment: Yes, thank you. I get the productId and stock count, bit not description or price. I think I need to add a select * to the product_type. I'm playing with the code to try and get it to work. Yay for the internet! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your error is more likely "Ambiguous column name 'productID'."  And, I'm guessing the join should be on that field as well:

```
select product_units.productID, count (stock)as available_count
from product_units
join  product_type ON product_type.productID = product_units.productID
group by product_units.productID
```

To select all rows from the product_type table use a `right outer join`:

```
select product_units.productID, count (stock)as available_count
from product_units
right outer join  product_type ON product_type.productID = product_units.productID
group by product_units.productID
```

To select all information from the product type table, do the aggregation first and then join:

```
select pt.*, pu.available_count
from (select productId, count(stock) as available_count
      from product_units
      group by productId
     ) pu join
     product_type pt
     on pt.productID = pu.productId;
```

Comment: You are right, apologies I got mixed up when I was typing the question. I've corrected the question. Thanks.

Comment: If I wanted to select all, with the above query, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Apologies, I meant if I wanted to select all from the product_type table with the above query.